# QDateTime Isodate with timezone ?

Tags: c++, qt, datetime, timezone

I'm looking for the datetime from qt to return me the string as an isodate but with the timezone.
I looked on the web for sometimes for my problem but found no solution

I just got this:

```
this->ui.dateEnd->dateTime().toString(Qt::ISODate);
```

giving me this:

```
1900-10-31T23:00:00Z
```

Or also this:

```
this->ui.dateEnd->dateTime().toUfc().toString(Qt::ISODate);
```

giving me this:

```
1900-10-31T23:00:00Z
```

and i want this:

```
1900-10-31T23:00:00+01.00.00
```

Thank you if someone have an idea!

Comment: `dateTime.toTimeSpec(Qt::OffsetFromUTC).toString(Qt::ISODate)` should work (according to docs), but it seems that [there is a bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-26161).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got around the bug that I mentioned in the comments:

```
QDateTime local = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
QDateTime utc = local.toUTC();
utc.setTimeSpec(Qt::LocalTime);

qint64 const utcOffset = utc.secsTo(local);

qDebug() << local.toString(Qt::ISODate);
qDebug() << utc.toString(Qt::ISODate);
qDebug() << utcOffset;

local.setUtcOffset(utcOffset);
qDebug() << local.toString(Qt::ISODate);
```

This outputs:

```
"2013-09-12T00:17:39"  
"2013-09-11T21:17:39"  
10800 
"2013-09-12T00:17:39+03:00"
```